# pandas apply on a column (valus is of type set) to retrieve the first element pop results in error

Tags: python, pandas, apply

The dataframe comprises of 2 columns, name (string) and key_set (set of string uuid)

```
df[df['key_set'].apply(lambda x: len(x) == 1)]['key_set'].apply(lambda x: x.pop())
```

Results in an error, which seems not possible as it is already filtered

```
pop from an empty set
```

where as the below works fine

```
df[df['key_set'].apply(lambda x: len(x) == 1)]['key_set'].apply(lambda x: next(iter(x)))
```

Comment: I guess you need `try` and `except` to handle the errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you first run one of that expressions `set.pop()` will change a mutable *set* inplace, so that each other expression running with same `set.pop()` will throw the error `KeyError: 'pop from an empty set'` due to exhausted set object.

Instead of redundant filtering, to collect the values and preserve the initial `df` with sets use the following approach (assuming that):

```
df['key_set'].apply(lambda s: np.nan if len(s) != 1 else s.copy().pop()).dropna()
```

Comment: ```df[df['key_set'].apply(lambda x: len(x) == 1)]['key_set'].apply(lambda x: print(id(x)))``` helped in understanding the issue ```id(x)``` returns the unique identifier